# Android BluetoothSocket connection returns zero

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-socket

Our device sends data via Bluetooth , In android app we need to read this data.

I am able to establish Bluetooth connection, and next I am calling a Thread to establish BluetoothSocket connection using BluetoothDevice. Here when the bytes are read it is returning as 0 (zero)
Also The while loop is running for only once.

Also the UUID that I have used in below code is from some Bluetooth Snippet code. Do I need to obtain the correct UUID of the device.

Please can anyone help?.If you give me the useful answer,it will be highly appreciated.

```
   //Calling ConnectThread after Bluetooth is paired
    public class ConnectThread extends Thread {
            private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
            private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
            private final UUID MY_UUID = UUID
                    .fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

            public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
                BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
                mmDevice = device;
                try {
                    String name = device.getName();
                    Log.e("Device Name ", name);
                    tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
                mmSocket = tmp;
            }

            public void run() {
                // mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                try {
                    mmSocket.connect();

                    ConnectedThread mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
                    mConnectedThread.start();
                } catch (IOException connectException) {
                    // try {
                    // mSocket.close();
                    // } catch (IOException closeException) { }
                    return;
                }
            }

            public void cancel() {
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }

        private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
            private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
            private final InputStream mmInStream;
            private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

            public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
                mmSocket = socket;
                InputStream tmpIn = null;
                OutputStream tmpOut = null;
                try {
                    tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                    tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
                mmInStream = tmpIn;
                mmOutStream = tmpOut;
            }

            public void run() {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int begin = 0;
                int bytes = 0;
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        // bytes += mmInStream.read(buffer, bytes, buffer.length
                        // - bytes);
                        if (mmSocket.isConnected()) {
                            Log.e("Socket is connected", "Socket is connected");
                        }
                        int numOfBytes = mmInStream.available();
                        Log.e("numOfBytes", String.valueOf(+numOfBytes));
                        bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                        // mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        // .sendToTarget();



                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }


i am struck and unable to read the data from the Bluetooth
```

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to obtain the correct UUID of the device.

Yes. You could use `getUuids()` of your `BluetoothDevice` which returns the supported features (UUIDs) of the remote device, or `fetchUuidsWithSdp()` if fresh UUIDs are desired.

> The while loop is running for only once.

It's because your code is throwing an error and your are handling this error and exit the loop

```
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // bytes += mmInStream.read(buffer, bytes, buffer.length
                    // - bytes);
                    if (mmSocket.isConnected()) {
                        Log.e("Socket is connected", "Socket is connected");
                    }
                    int numOfBytes = mmInStream.available();
                    Log.e("numOfBytes", String.valueOf(+numOfBytes));
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                    // mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                    // .sendToTarget();



                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // THIS BREAK INTERRUPT YOUR WHILE-LOOP SENTENCE
                    break;
                }
            }
```

> Here when the bytes are read it is returning as 0

Because you created a InputStream of a socket with It's not connected to anything (Because the UUID which you created to generate the socket doesn't exist in the device where you made your bluetooth connection)

**EDIT**

Other way to get uuids is config the broadcast receiver to get back the uuids:

```
//Register the BroadcastReceiver
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_UUID);
//Set your other filters
registerReceiver(ActionFoundReceiver, filter); // Don't forget to unregister during onDestroy
```

And create your BroadcastRecievier to get the UUIDs:

```
  private final BroadcastReceiver ActionFoundReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     String action = intent.getAction();

       if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_UUID.equals(action)) {
         BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
         Parcelable[] uuidExtra = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_UUID);
         for (int i=0; i<uuidExtra.length; i++) {
         Log.i("TEST-UUIDS","Device: " + device.getName() + ", " + device + ", Service: " + uuidExtra[i].toString());
         }
       } 
       else if(BluetoothDevice.YOUR_OTHER_ACTION_1){
        //YOUR CODE FOR ACTION 1

       } 
       else if(BluetoothDevice.YOUR_OTHER_ACTION_2){
        //YOUR CODE FOR ACTION 2

       } 

    }
  };
```

Note: Not every bluetooth device show their service uuids'

Comment: Thank you for reply Miguel.

Comment: I tried to getUuids using below code. But device.getUuids(); is returning null . For your information BluetoothDevice object  is not null but device.getUuids() is null.                                                                                    BluetoothDevice device;try {
       ParcelUuid[] uuids = device.getUuids();
       for (ParcelUuid ep : uuids) {
        Log.e("UUID records : ", ep.toString());
       }
      } catch (Exception e) {
       Log.e("Exceptoin e", e.toString());
      }

Comment: Are you connecting with the device using his address or discovering via scan and them connecting with the device?

Comment: BluethoothDevice object I am discovering via scan and then trying to fetch the device.getUuids();, but it is returning null.

Comment: Check if it's possible to get uuids back when is discovering devices

Comment: Hi Miguel, Now I am able to get uuid I fetched it immediatly after the scan, But the problem now if its fetching the same uuid that I mentioned in the above code "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", And again the byte data is 0 and contol goes to bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer); there is no responce from there . kindly provide your valuable inputs

Comment: Try to read your inputstream when the socket is connected inside mmSocket.isConnected() if sentence.

Comment: Tried adding mmInStream.read(buffer); inside the if sentence mmSocket.isConnected(), but same issue there no responce after mmInStream.read its not evening going to next instruction or catch block while debugging no response,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111446/discussion-between-miguel-benitez-and-android-developing).